# Did Sadducees contribute to halacha?

Tags: kohen-priest, sanhedrin, sadducees

We know that Sadducees served on the Sanhedrin and even became high priests.  [Yoma 19b]  They did not believe in the afterlife or the resurrection of the dead, but this does not mean their understanding in other areas was deficient.  Are there any halachot that were accepted and attributed to rabbis known to be Sadducees?  Specifics?

**Edit:**  The suggested duplicate: [Did the Sadducees get anything right?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/108874/did-the-sadducees-get-anything-right)
asked what the Sadducees agreed with the Pharisees on.  I asked what novelty did the Sadducees contribute that became part of halacha.

Comment: They didn't accept the Oral Torah either.

Comment: They contributed to halakha in that the rabbis created a number of laws specifically because of them, though I don't think that's what you meant with this question.

Comment: Is it possible to sit on the sanhedrin for decades and not somehow contribute to halakha?

Comment: If something of the Sadducees was accepted as Halacha, wouldn’t that by definition be the Sadducees and Pharisees being in agreement? I agree with the duplicate closure.

Comment: @DonielF -- I am asking for something that the Sadducees came up with on their own and that was accepted as halacha, if it exists.  (Not worth discussing further.  You guys go ahead with your little games and Shabbat Shalom to all.)

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi Isn’t that a subset of that question then? Shabbat Shalom to you too.