# Did Reform add anything new vis-a-vis responsa?

Tags: halacha, reform-judaism

Teshuvot, or responsa, are the way much halacha has been settled since the Talmudic era. When the Reform movement started, did it continue this tradition of leading rabbis writing teshuvot, or did it stop the practice? If Reform rabbis do indeed write teshuvot, have any been accepted by Traditional Judaism?

This is similar to my [Sadducee](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/108874/19691) question but only here I am asking about the reform movement.

Comment: Jonathan, there is a whole corpus of Reform teshuvot spanning back to 1840's Germany. We can debate the legitimacy thereof, but Reform rabbis write up statements they call responsa on a pretty regular basis

Comment: If you wish to know about Reform responsa, look up the Central Conference of American Rabbis. On their site is a link “Rabbi’s voice” which then has a list of Reform responsa with some on line. Many are not consistent with Orthodoxy as has been mentioned.  I suppose you should ask your Rav if you are allowed to go that far or if it would be forbidden.

Comment: @Damila - Why not make that an answer?

Comment: @Danny Schoemann Thank you. My comment does not really answer the OP question. It was a response to Jonathan saying he found the concept fascinating. Anyway, if looks like a lot of the comments have been deleted. So I will give it a go.

Comment: I think the question is good (+1) but it is phrased badly: do you mean do they do responsa or whether something *from their responsa* made its way to our Halachah?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reform Judaism has responsa which are intended to address practical issues within the framework of Reform Judaism. (As noted by JoshK in comment.)

As for something “new”, one example is the question of whether a transgender female (with objectively male external genetalia) who converts need a *milah gerim*. I am not sure that is addressed specifically elsewhere.

A ruling that is considerably different involves “who is a Jew?”  A person with a Jewish father and non-Jewish mother, who also does public acts of Jewish identity, is Jewish. (Note: As I understand it, contrary to popular belief, it is not simply “either parent Jewish = child is Jewish,” it is just that they do not require conversion anymore.)

I am not aware of anything that started with Reform and was adopted by Orthodox Rabbonim.

To see the Reform responsa, including some that have since been superseded, look up the Central Conference of American Rabbis. On their page is “Rabbinic Voice” which leads to “Reform responsa.”

> The CCAR applies Jewish scholarship and transition to contemporary issues through the creation of Reform Responsa, based on the historic Jewish system of providing answers to questions about Judaism and Jewish living.

I will add the link if it is allowed on this site.

Disclaimers:

1. I am not Reform and do not claim to represent their position.
2. It is possible that you should ask your Rav if you are permitted to read the responsa.

Comment: this answer is very good but is already flirting with *lifnei ever*, a link would probably be even more problematic in that regard

Comment: Yeah, I originally put it as a comment (in a response to a response to your more general comment.) I guess leading readers to the site could be *l”i* but for the answer as is, everyone is aware that Reform exists. Anyway, I will leave the link out.

Comment: @Damila Thank you for your answer and comments. I would very much like the link. I am orthodox and do not intend to become reform but I would be interested in learning about their community and rulings. You can reach me at r.jonathanhenryhorowitz@gmail.com to send me the link.

Comment: @JoshK Thank you for editing my question. It prompted for a good answer.

Comment: @Jonathan, this site is very much a collaborative effort, we're here to help each other. All I did was follow your comments on the original post to help get at what you were really looking for. Kol tuv! :)

Comment: I don't see a problem with a properly-labeled link.  I think I've linked to a Reform responsum somewhere in the past.  So long as it's clear to the reader what's beyond the link, why would that be *lifnei ever*?

Comment: Thanks @Monica Cellio. I’ve been a lurker on this site a couple years, I am pretty sure it is what got me into SE in the first place. I just did not want to step on any toes. I know all are welcome here but it seems most (not all!) of the regular posters are pretty frum. I don’t personally think it is lifnei iver and I gave the name of the org. Anyone who’s heard of a search engine can easily find it.

Comment: @JoshK That was a good thought to see my comments. The edit worked nicely.  :)

Comment: @Monica there's a respectful, well thought-out answer to your question lurking somewhere in my mind; give me a couple of days and BN I'll come up with it. I'll even do my best to avoid referencing *keffir* limes ;)